Linear transformation involving complex phases and discrete Fourier transform coefficients
Consider a real-valued square matrix $A$ of dimension $N\times N$, whose $i,j$ entry is represented by $A_{ij}$, and some unknown real-valued vector $\vec{v}=(v_1,...,v_j,...,v_N)$.
Given the equation:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_j A_{ij}v_j =e^{i\lambda}\sum_{j}A_{ij}v_j e^{-ix_j},\hspace{10pt}\lambda,x_j\in{\mathbb{R}},
\end{eqnarray}
is there a way to determine the solution of the $v_j$'s by making some ansatz about their form? I am thinking some sort of discrete Fourier transformation result might help, but have no clue about whether it is in general possible to obtain a closed-form for the solution.

All quantities are given, solve for vector v? Then just a system of linear equations, right?
